# How to restrict the file picker in only one location in c# metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a metro app in C#. I'm using the file picker to save and open the file. Now, I want to restrict the users to only one location. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to restrict the users to only one location with the FilePicker.  Here is a [source from the forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1e59c78f-6c37-4915-b731-714613030b72) that confirms that.  One possibility is that you could set the location that you want them to use with the [SuggestedStartLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.suggestedstartlocation.aspx), and then most people may use that default location.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the UI creatively. Open a screen where you have preloaded the files in some sort of gridview or listview from your chosen location and allow the users to select from among those.